# Sacar promedio de array bidimensionales en java

Tags: java

tengo que hacer una funcion donde tome un array bidimesional y con este devolver un array con los promedios de cada fila.

este es el codigo que hice pero solo me devuelve el promedio de todo el array

```
public static float[] matriz(float[][] array) {
    float[] promediofinal = {1, 2, 3};
    float suma = 0;
    float promedio = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
            suma += array[i][j];
            promedio = suma / array.length;
            promediofinal = new float[]{promedio};
        }

    }
    return promediofinal;
}
```

Comment: mueve tu variable `suma` dentro del primer ciclo `for`, pues nunca *reinicias* la variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ver si te sirve

```
public class PromedioMatriz {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        //Instanciamos la clase escaner en la variable teclado
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        //pedimos las filas por consola
        System.out.println("Ponga filas; ");
        //recogemos las filas en la variable filas
        int filas = teclado.nextInt();
        //pedimos las columnas por consola
        System.out.println("Ponga columnas; ");
        //recogemos las columnas en la variable columnas
        int columnas = teclado.nextInt();
        //declaramos un array bidimensional con los limites de filas y columnas
        float[][] matriz = new float[filas][columnas];
        //separamos el código anterior del siguiente con dos líneas en blanco
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
     
        //bucle que recorre filas
        for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
            //almacenamos en las filas un número incremental coincidente con la variable i
            matriz[i][0] = i;
            //bucle que recorre las columnas
            for (int j = 0; j < matriz[i].length; j++) {
                //declaramos variable float con valor aleatorio entre 0 y 25
                float numero = (float)(Math.random() * 25 + 1);;
                //almacenmos ese valor en cada columna
                matriz[i][j] = numero;
            }
        }
     
        //declaramos array float que recogerá los promedios del anterior array y llamamos al método para obtener dichos valores
        float[] promedios = matriz(matriz);
        //declaramos variable float para recoger suma promedios
        float sumaPromedios = 0;

        //imprimimos en consola los valores de la matriz llamando al método correspondiente
        System.out.println("El array bidimensional tiene: " +
             matriz.length + " filas y " + matriz[0].length + " columnas");
        System.out.println("Sus valores son: ");
        metodoMostrarArray(matriz);
        //creamos línea en blanco
        System.out.println("");

        //escribimos el número de filas del array de promedios
        System.out.println("El array de promedios tiene " + promedios.length + " filas");
        //bucle que recorre los valores del array de promedios
        for (int i = 0; i < promedios.length; i++) {
            //mostramos el promedio de cada fila
            System.out.println("Promedio fila " + (i + 1) + " es de: " + promedios[i]);
            //sumamos los valores de cada fila
            sumaPromedios += promedios[i];
        }
        //fila en blanco
        System.out.println("");
        //calcuamos el promedio total
        System.out.println("El Promedio total es de: " + (sumaPromedios / promedios.length));
    }
    //calculamos los prmedios por filas del array bidimensional
    public static float[] matriz(float[][] array) {
        //creamos un nuevo array que recogerá el promedio por cada fila
        float[] promedios = new float[array.length];

        //bucle que recorre las filas
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            //declaramos en cada iteración una variable float para la suma de las columnas de cada fila
            float suma = 0;
            //bucle que recorre las columnas
            for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
                //sumamos las columnas en la variable suma
                suma += array[i][j];
            }
            //calculamos el promedio dividiendo la suma de columnas de cada fila entre el número de filas
            float promedio = suma / array.length;
            //añadimos ese valor al array de promedios
            promedios[i] = promedio;
        }
        //retornamos el array
        return promedios;
    }
    //metodo que muestra en consola el array bidimensional 
    public static void metodoMostrarArray(float[][] array){      
        int columnas = array[0].length;
        //bucle que recorre las filas        
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            //creamos un contador para las columnas
            int contador = 0;
            //bucle que recorre las columnas
            for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
                //escribimos el valor del array en la posición del bucle seguido de coma
                System.out.print(array[i][j] + ", ");
                //por cada iteración incrementamos una columna
                contador++;
            }
            //si el contador es igual al número de columnas del array
            if (contador == columnas){
               //Damos una linea para escribir los valores por filas
               System.out.print("\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: si muchas gracias!!

Comment: @eli, por favor, si te encaja la respuesta dale al check para aceptarla y así cerrar la pregunta. Gracias